# OPENCV how to speed up imshow?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm developing a little program in which there is a circle handled by the mouse pointer that moves in real time over an image.

I achieved to do that using 
    `cvSetMouseCallback()`
but it works fine only when the window is set as
    `CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE`
and the image size is not too big (less then 400x400). I realized that the problem is in the
    `imShow()`
function that wastes to much time.
I wanted to use
   `cv::updateWindow()`
function to force the window updating but I get 
    `undefined reference to`
error. What can I do to speed up my application? Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you paste that undefined reference error? Clearly linker lacks some library during linking process.

Comment: main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `cv::updateWindow(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'

Comment: What is your system and compiler?

Comment: [g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3] with [Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `cv::updateWindow()` is only for OpenGL window callbacks (it is used together with `cv::setOpenGlDrawCallback()`).

Can you provide the part of the source code where you are drawing the circle over the image? And also, what is the size of the image you are trying to draw on?